# MJPG streaming with a Raspberry Pi and a webcam

Tags: video-streaming, webcam, raspberry-pi

So I need to have a network camera using a Raspberry pi, and have followed [this](http://wolfpaulus.com/journal/embedded/raspberrypi_webcam) tutorial. The device is serving the test streaming page, however all of the places where the stream should be embedded are blank. I am using a PS3 eyetoy camera with the Raspbian Wheezy distro. This is the log I receive when starting the server:

```
MJPG Streamer Version: svn rev: 3:165
 i: Using V4L2 device.: /dev/video0
 i: Desired Resolution: 640 x 480
 i: Frames Per Second.: 5
 i: Format............: MJPEG
Adding control for Pan (relative)
UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Adding control for Tilt (relative)
UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Adding control for Pan Reset
UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Adding control for Tilt Reset
UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Adding control for Pan/tilt Reset
UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Adding control for Focus (absolute)
UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mapping control for Pan (relative)
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mapping control for Tilt (relative)
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mapping control for Pan Reset
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mapping control for Tilt Reset
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mapping control for Pan/tilt Reset
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mapping control for Focus (absolute)
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mapping control for LED1 Mode
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mapping control for LED1 Frequency
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mapping control for Disable video processing
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mapping control for Raw bits per pixel
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 o: www-folder-path...: ./www/
 o: HTTP TCP port.....: 8080
 o: username:password.: disabled
 o: commands..........: enabled
```

I have not found any explanation of this error, and don't know what problem it could be referring to.

Answer (score 11):

the ps3 camera doesn't seem to support mjpeg, but it does support YUYV format. Try initialising the stream with the -y flag. eg:

```
mjpg_streamer -i "/usr/lib/input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -y  -r 320x240 -f 15" -o "/usr/lib/output_http.so -p 8090 -w ./www"
```

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, the errors you have listed are related to the dynctrls of the Linux-UVC driver, and not to the image format mjpeg or yuyv.

It appears as though your camera does support the mjpeg format, however, your current camera/driver lacking support for the dynctrls listed (i.e. your camera does not have the ability for pan/tilt/focus/etc., or mjpeg encountered an error when trying to access/set the controls listed), you can disable the dynctrls (and therefore eliminate the errors you recieved by using the `-n` flag when starting mjpg-streamer.

Something like this:

```
./mjpg_streamer -i "./input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -n" -o "./output_http.so -p 8090"
```

will start streaming on port 8090 of the raspberry pi's ip address.

To access the stream on your local network, go to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8090/?action=stream` or insert `<img src="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8090/?action=stream">` into an accessible html page.  Replaceing `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with the LOCAL IP address of your raspberry pi.

To access the stream at a remote location (not on the same local network as the pi), replace `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with the EXTERNAL IP of the network the raspberry pi resides on (and edit your router settings to forward requests to port `8090` to the raspberry pi's LOCAL IP address).

Comment: -n totally solved the issue for me - makes a lot of sense, too. I have a basic logitech webcam connected adn of course it does not support pan/tilt etc.

Comment: Solved the issue with mjpeg streamer and a logitech webcam for me, same error 9 years later!